# What happens when you create a gap on your board in Wingspan?

Tags: wingspan

With the base game, whenever you play a bird, it's final. However, with the expansions, there's options to create empty spaces on your board. What happens when you do this?

Imagine this scenario:

- play a regular bird
- play one of the "play this bird sideways so it covers to fields" birds
- play another regular bird
- play a bird that can be played on top of an existing bird, on top of the sideways bird

Now what happens?

- Do I get to pick which of the two fields the new bird goes in? Or must it be the left one?
- Do the birds to the right of it move inwards after playing it?

If they don't move in:

- can I play a new bird in the hole? (Or must I, even, when playing a bird on that row?)
- What happens when I take that action? Do I skip the hole? Do I start from the hole and skip the birds to the right? Do I resolve the action shown in the hole? (That last one seems too powerful, but you never know?)
- If I use a bird that moves when activated, does it go into the slot and become trapped, or does it go to the right-most opening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> there's options to create empty spaces on your board.

No. From the [FAQ](https://stonemaiergames.com/games/wingspan/wingspan-european-expansion/):

> **How do I play a bird on top of a sideways bird?**
>
> Some birds like the European Roller allow you to place the card sideways on your player mat, filling two spots. If you then play a bird like the Common Buzzard on top of a sideways bird, the Common Buzzard would also be placed sideways, completely covering the sideways bird.